# Testacular does not find web-app

Tags: angularjs, xampp, karma-runner

I try to run my e2e test on my local mac. Testacular finds all the test and runs them. They all fail, because testacular does not using the right URLs. All my browser().navigateTo() enter the nirvana and not the right page. It's seams like the proxy-property does not work. At the moment my config looks like this:

```
basePath = '';

files = [
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
  './e2e/*.js'
];

browsers = ['Safari'];

urlRoot = '/__testacular/';

proxies = {
    '/': 'http://localhost:80/test/index.html#/'
};

autoWatch = true;
singleRun = false;
```

I appreciate all kind of tips! THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works for me (adapted to your config) is:

```
basePath = '..';

files = [
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
  './test/e2e/*.js'
];

urlRoot = '/__testacular/';

proxies = {
    '/': 'http://localhost/'
};
```